# Sharepoint Designer 2013/2010 Workflow Platform: How to compare current item to other calendar events

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I was in here before about double booking but I got no solutions. I have continued to try solutions for the issue but it all circled back to one **KEY** thing I could not seem to do:

Compare the current item being evaluated and comparing it's columns to other calendar event columns.

Here is the scenario so we are **very** clear:

I create a meeting event for Room A at 12:00pm to 1:00 pm. When that event is created, what I **want** to do is have a workflow that takes that event and checks to see if that same room is scheduled within the requested time period and date(s). If there already is a booking of that room during that time period, the event should be deleted and the person should be notified (the person who tried to book).

Thanks in advanced for responses.

-Colton

Comment: Which version of the workflow engine are you using?

Comment: We are not using Workflow Manager. Only the 2010 platform that comes with Sharepoint Designer 2013.